# Modeling an interface with a generic array

Tags: typescript, generics

I would like to model an interface that has array that accepts objects as long as they extend a particular interface. I'm still learning Generics, so please bear with me.

Here's my "base" interface:

```
export interface IEntry {
  sys: {
    contentType: {
      . . .
    }
  }
}
```

and my extended interface:

```
export interface IWorkSample extends IEntry {
  fields: {
    . . .
  }
}
```

Here's the interface that has the array:

```
export interface IEntries {
  items: IEntry[]; <- doesn't allow for IWorkSample or future interfaces
  limit: number;
  skip: number;
  sys: {
    type: string;
  };
  total: number;
}
```

I can of course do:

```
items: IWorkCategory[] | IWorkSample[];
```

but then I have to keep adding types.

I'd like to be able to write the `IEntries` interface to allow `items` to contain objects that extend `IEntry`. I'm reading the [Generics Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html), but obviously coming up short.

I can use `items: any[]`, but that of course doesn't guarantee the objects will have properties I'll expect in the future. Can someone please help me out with an example that makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can introduce a type parameter that extends `IEntry` like below:

```
interface IEntries<T extends IEntry> {
    items: T[];
    // ...
}
```

And use it like:

```
let entries: IEntries<IWorkSample> = {
    items: ... // IWorkSample[] here
}
```

Comment: `IEntries` doesn't extend `IEntry` though... `items` is an array of types that extend `IEntry`...or am I completely missing the point?

Comment: Correct. That is what the example above shows as well `IEntries` does not extend `IEntry` only the type parameter `T` extends `IEntry`.

Comment: So far so good. I'm able to access the properties I expect now. Thank you!